# Newbie needs to know how to parse a whole text group like this

Tags: c#, .net

I need to parse a textfile with about 10000 groupings like this

```
group "C_BatTemp" -- block-group
{
 block: "Constant"
 flags: BLOCK|COLLAPSED
}
    -- Skipping output Out1
    p_untitled_P_real_T_0[1]
    {
     type:    flt(64,IEEE)*
     alias:   "Value"
     flags: PARAM
    }

endgroup -- block-group "C_BatTemp"
```

The desired objects I expect the parser to fill look like this

```
    string Varname = "C_BatTemp";
    string GroupType = "Constant";
    string BaseAdressName = "p_untitled_P_real_T_0";
    int AdressOffset = 1; // number in parenthesis p_untitled_P_real_T_0[1]<----
    string VarType = "flt(64, IEEE)";
    bool IsPointer = true; // true if VarType is "flt(64, IEEE)*" , 
    //false if "flt(64, IEEE)"        
    string VarAlias = "Value";
```

What is the best way of parsing this ??

How sould I start ?

Comment: I think you need to add more details on the syntax of the language you are trying to parse.  Where are braces required?  It appears that the sequence `--` introduces a comment -- is that true?  It looks like you may be able to parse this with some kind of finite state automaton (e.g. regex), but depending on the rules of the language you may need a more complex lexer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution might be using a regular expression. I quickly made up one, but it might require some additional tuning to fit your exact needs. It works for your example, but might fail for other inputs. The expression is very much tailored to the given example especially in respect to line breaks and comments.

**CODE**

```
String input =
@"group ""C_BatTemp"" -- block-group
{
 block: ""Constant""
 flags: BLOCK|COLLAPSED
}
        -- Skipping output Out1
        p_untitled_P_real_T_0[1]
        {
         type:    flt(64,IEEE)*
         alias:   ""Value""
         flags: PARAM
        }

endgroup -- block-group ""C_BatTemp""";

String pattern = @"^group\W*""(?<varname>[^""]*)""[^{]*{\W*block:\W*""(?<grouptype>[^""]*)""[^}]*}$(\W*--.*$)*\W*(?<baseaddressname>[^[]*)\[(?<addressoffset>[^\]]*)][^{]*{\W*type:\W*(?<vartype>.*)$\W*alias:\W*""(?<alias>[^""]*)""[^}]*}\W*endgroup.*$";

foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input.Replace("\r\n", "\n"), pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline))
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["varname"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["grouptype"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["baseaddressname"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["addressoffset"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["vartype"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["vartype"].Value.EndsWith("*"));
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["alias"].Value);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
C_BatTemp
Constant
p_untitled_P_real_T_0
1
flt(64,IEEE)*
True
Value
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar recently.

Break each block of data into records (would these be your 'groups'?).  Extract each element you need from each record using Regular Expressions.

Without a clearer idea of the data I can't elaborate.